# how to zoom in and zoom out using form type range using jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how how to zoom in and zoom out using `form type range` in jquery.

I am trying to zoom in and zoom out `div class` but I don't know how to zoom using jquery can any one help.

```
<input type="text" >
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Show us your html / jQuery code, and what explain us, what do you want to achive, what did you tried so far.

Comment: do you know Microsoft word document it zoom page by plus and minus i want like that for html page

Comment: Please read it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Try setting the range value to a CSS style like height and width and thereby reducing or increasing the range slider the size will change giving the effect of zoom in and zoom out.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 has a new `zoom` property, but you may need to use vendor prefixes on it depending on your browser.

To increase the size of a div, you can use positive values (> 1) and to decrease you can use negative values

**JavaScript Solution**

```js
var range = document.getElementById("my-range");
var square = document.getElementById("square");

range.addEventListener("change", function() {
    square.style.zoom = this.value; 
});
```

```css
#square {
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="my-range" type="range" step="0.25" min="0.25" max="4" />

<div id="square"></div>
```

**jQuery solution**

```js
$("#my-range").on("change", function() {
    $("#square").css({"zoom": $(this).val() });
});
```

```css
#square {
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="my-range" type="range" step="0.25" min="0.25" max="4" />

<div id="square"></div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom